# OpenCV/EMGU (C#) detection of objects

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to write some image detection code for a pick and place machine.  I'm new to OpenCV and have been going through a lot of examples - but still ahve two outstanding questions.  The first one I think I have a solution for but I'm lost on the second.

I'm trying to detect the offset and angle of the bottom of a part. Essentially, how far is the object from the cross (just an indicator of the center of the frame), and what the angle of rotation the part has about the part's center. I've used filters to show the pads of the components.

[image: bottom pads of surface mount part]

I'm pretty sure that I want to implement something like this http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/ - but I'm not sure how to translate the code into C# (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  Any pointers would be helpful.

One issue is if the part is smaller than the needle that's holding it and you can see both the part and the needle.

[image: 0402 resistor and needle]

The square bit is the part I want to detect.  The round part is part of the needle that is still exposed.  I've got no clue how to approach this - I'm thinking something along the lines of detecting the straight lines and discarding the curved ones to generate a shape.  Again, I'm interested in the offset from the center and the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

First you should detect every Object with [findContours](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/028cb9c4-eb4b-aa5d-242e-273ac7e227e2.htm). Then you can use the [minimum area rectangle function](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Minimum_Area_Rectangle_in_CSharp) on every found contour. I assume you know the size and coordiantes of your cross so you can use the Center Coordinates of the MCvBox2D to get the Offset to it. Furthermore you can read the angle property of the box so it should fit your purpose.

For the second part i would try to fit a least square reactangle. The round part seems to be very small compared to the square one so maybe it will work.

Maybe the [Detection of Quadrilaterlas](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/) in the AForge Library could help you too.

Edit:
To merge your the contours i would try something like this:

```
 Rectangle merged = New Rectangle(New Point(img.Width, img.Height), New Size(0, 0)); //img is your binarized image
 Contour<Point> Pad_contours= img.FindContours(CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST);
   while(Pad_contours !=null)
   {

     if(Pad_contours.Area <Pad_Area_max &&Pad_contours>Pad_Area_min)//Filter Pads to avoid false positive Contours
     {
     //Merge Pad contours into a single rectangle
         if(merged.Height >0)
         merged.Bottom=Math.Max(merged.Bottom,Pad_Contours.BoundingRectangle.Bottom);
         else
         merged.Height = contours.BoundingRectangle.Height;

         merged.Top=Math.Min(merged.Top,Pad_Contours.BoundingRectangle.Top);
         merged.Left=math.Min(merged.Left,Pad_Contours.BoundingRectangle.Left);

         if(merged.Width>0)
         merged.Right=Max(merged.Right,pad_Contours.BoundingRectangle.Right);
         else
         merged.Width=Pad_Contours.BoundingRectangle.Width;
     }
     //get next Pad
         If(Pad_contours.VNext==null)
         Pad_contours=Pad_contours.HNext;
         else
         Pad_contours = Pad_contours.VNext;
  }
```

The rectangle "merged" should enclose all your Pads now. The problem is you wont get an angle this way because the rectangle is always vertically 90°. To solve this I would iterate through the contours like shown above and store every point of every contour in an extra datacontainer. Then I would use the minimum area rectangle function mentioned above and apply it on all gathered points. This should give you a bounding rectangle with an angle property.

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to merge the contours for part A then apply the find rectangle -- it's just one part and all you see are the copper pads underneath it (http://i.imgur.com/cUynGrU.png).